# Integral of exponential function with polynomial arguments with degree two $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-ax^2}e^{-2bx}dx$.

Tags: calculus, integration

I have been using the following definite integral of exponential function for ages  without knowing how to show it.

> $$
> \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-ax^2}e^{-2bx}dx=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}e^{\frac{b^2}{a}}.
> $$

Can anybody give some hints?

Comment: I think you need a $x^2$ in the integral.

Comment: @Chinny84 Modified. Thanks.

Comment: Also see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/374433/calculating-int-infty-infty-e-ax2eibxdx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$ 
\begin{align} 
I &=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\exp\left[-ax^2-2bx\color{red}{-\frac{b^2}{a}+\frac{b^2}{a}}\right]\,dx \\ 
&=e^{\frac{b^2}{a}}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\exp\left[-\left(\sqrt{a}x+\frac{b}{\sqrt{a}}\right)^2\right]\,dx \\ 
&\qquad\color{blue}{\left\{t=\sqrt{a}x+\frac{b}{\sqrt{a}} \implies dt=\sqrt{a}\,dx\right\}} \\ 
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}\,e^{\frac{b^2}{a}}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-t^2}\,dt = \color{red}{\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}\,e^{\frac{b^2}{a}}} 
\end{align} 
$$ 
Where $\{\,\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-t^2}\,dt=\sqrt{\pi}\,\}$ is [Gaussian Integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral).

Answer (score 0):

Complete the square in the exponent.  Convert the integrand into

$$\int e^k e^{(-(x-a)^2/2)}\ dx$$

then

$$e^k \int e^{x^2/2}\ dx$$

Answer (score 0):

$$I=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-ax^2}e^{-2bx}dx=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-(ax^2+2bx)}dx$$
now:
$$ax^2+2bx=\left(\sqrt{a}x+\frac{b}{\sqrt{a}}\right)^2-\frac{b^2}{a}$$
so our integral becomes:
$$I=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\left(\left(\sqrt{a}x+\frac{b}{\sqrt{a}}\right)^2-\frac{b^2}{a}\right)}dx=e^{\frac{b^2}{a}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\left(\sqrt{a}x+\frac{b}{\sqrt{a}}\right)^2}dx$$
now we let:
$$u=\sqrt{a}x+\frac{b}{\sqrt{a}}$$
$$dx=\frac{du}{\sqrt{a}}$$
so now our integral becomes:
$$I=\frac{e^{\frac{b^2}{a}}}{\sqrt{a}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-u^2}du=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}e^{\frac{b^2}{a}}$$
as this integral is a standard integral called the gaussian integral:

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GaussianIntegral.html

and i mentioned how to solve it here:
[Determine whether the integral $ \int^{+\infty}_0\frac{e^{-t}} {\sqrt t} \, dt$ converges or diverges?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2873036/determine-whether-the-integral-int-infty-0-frace-t-sqrt-t-dt/2873041#2873041)