# Integrating $\int_{-\infty} ^\infty \frac{1}{4\pi} e^{-\frac{1}{8}((u+v)^2+(u-v)^2)} dv$

Tags: calculus, integration, normal-distribution

It may seem like a very basic question to some but I struggle at integrating $$\int_{-\infty} 
^\infty \frac{1}{4\pi} e^{-\frac{1}{8}((u+v)^2+(u-v)^2)} dv$$

It gives me the error function $\mathrm{erf}(x)$ when I try to calculate it online which I am not familiar with.

Can anyone help me out please?

Comment: the erf function is defined as: $erf(x) = \int_0^x{e ^{-t^2}dt}$.

Comment: The exponent better have a minus sign!

Comment: Yes there is, my mistake! I put the original integral.

Comment: Are you sure the integral is from $\infty$ to $\infty$? Its value is just zero, then.

Comment: $\int_{-\infty} 
^\infty \frac{1}{4\pi} e^{-\frac{1}{8}((u+v)^2+(u-v)^2)} dv$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by looking at the exponent:$$(u+v)^2+(u-v)^2=u^2+2uv+v^2+u^2-2uv+v^2=2u^2+2v^2$$
Then the integral becomes:
$$I=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{4\pi} e^{-\frac{1}{8}((u+v)^2+(u-v)^2)} dv=\frac1{4\pi}e^{-\frac{u^2}{4}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\frac{v^2}{4}}dv$$
Change the variable $x=v/2$, so $dv=2dx$ and $$I=\frac 1{2\pi}e^{-\frac{u^2}{4}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2}dx$$
Let's call $$G=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2}dx$$
Then $$G^2=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2}dx\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-y^2}dy=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-(x^2+y^2)}dxdy$$
Transforming to polar coordinates
$$G^2=\int_0^\infty dr\int_0^{2\pi}d\theta re^{-r^2}=2\pi\int_0^\infty  re^{-r^2}dr$$
Change the variable again $z=r^2$. Then $dz=2rdr$. I hope you can continue from here.

Answer (score 1):

$$(u+v)^2+(u-v)^2=(u^2+2uv+v^2)+(u^2-2uv+v^2)=2(u^2+v^2)$$
now lets take a look at the exponential:
$$e^{-\frac14(u^2+v^2)}=e^{-\frac{u^2}4}e^{-\frac{v^2}4}$$
we can clean the integral up a bit now:
$$I=\frac{e^{-\frac{u^2}4}}{4\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-v^2/4}dv$$
if we make the substitution $x=v/2\Rightarrow dv=2dx$ and so:
$$I=\frac{e^{-u^2/4}}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2}dx$$
and this is the famous gaussian integral, which the error function is the finite version of with a scaling factor. In my answer to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2873036/determine-whether-the-integral-int-infty-0-frace-t-sqrt-t-dt/2873041#2873041) question I derived why this was true so you can take a look at that

Comment: Thank you for linking your detailed answer, appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

$(u+v)^2+(u-v)^2=2u^2+2v^2$ so the integral is $\frac{e^{-\frac{u^2}{4}}}{4\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\frac{v^2}{4}}dv=\frac{e^{-\frac{u^2}{4}}}{2\sqrt{\pi}}$.

Note:    There is no $x$ in the expression!  How did you get $erf(x)$?  The upper limit would have been $x$, not $\infty$.

Comment: There's a misunderstanding: I meant the error function erf was an answer to this integral.

Comment: If the limits are as you described, the integral is simply $erf(\infty)=1$ times the correct constant, so using $erf$ in this context doesn't make sense.